# Not aligning correctly CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgdmhr35/

**CSS,**

```
.container {
    display: grid; 
    /* grid-template-columns: 100px autp; 
    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 200px 50px; */
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "nav nav"
    "main main"
    "footer footer";
    grid-gap: .2em;
```

But, for some reason, I cannot get this to work properly. Also, I am not sure my Tablet @media query is correct.

Comment: I can't reach what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I cannot make the elements on the **left** share equal width. And main to be the bigger one, this is under **Tablet* device.

Comment: Can you add some specifics to your diagram to explain the sizes you want your columns and rows to be? Resizing the JS Fiddle you link to there's inconsistent behaviour (which I understand is the problem) but I don't know what behaviour you specifically want without making guesses.

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve it. Thanks a lot for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just specified 3 columns with `grid-template-columns` to the `.root` element and make the `main` element using the remaining width with `grid-column-end`.
You can check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdelrhman-arnos/v4yewaos/1/).

Comment: I will mark your post  as the answer, even if it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Thank you :D @JohnSmith